# Order of answers

Tags: discussion

Looking at the answers on a recently closed CW post about applications of pure math, I noticed that the answers were ordered by time posted, and not votes. Is this a new change? Is there a way to choose the ordering?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look just above the first answer. There are three tabs to order the posts by 'active', 'oldest', and 'votes.' Your selection is *sticky* so you may have inadvertently changed the ordering of that post. The wiki state should have no effect on the sort order.

Comment: Although if there's an accepted answer I think it rises to the top no matter which of the three tabs you select.

Comment: @Gerry: Under the condition it is not answered by the OP itself.